# Live streaming with play back back functionality

Tags: android, playback

I need to develop live DVR with play back functionality with live streaming of radio. 
Like already some application doing:[V Radio Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=audis.mobile.VRadioRecorderLite.views).
The main thing i need the play back functionality and live streaming. 
Like if User listened 20sec of radio then he can rewind to the 10sec.

Answer (score 0):

First download live stream byte byte and cache it locally. then play radio from that cache and for recording save that file to other recording directory.
here is the code. here i use AudioTrack but you can use media player and set source to media player that cache file for play.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Decoder mDecoder;
    private AudioTrack mAudioTrack;
    File downloadingMediaFile;
    FileOutputStream out;
    Button stop, start;
    boolean isStop;
    Thread DownloadThread;
    String url = "http://stream.laut.fm/darksynthradio?type=.mp3/;stream.mp3";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.continer, AudioVisualizationFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        isStop = true;
        stop.setClickable(false);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isStop = true;
                start.setClickable(true);
                stop.setClickable(false);

                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                downloadingMediaFile = new File("/storage/sdcard0/", new Date() + ".mp3");
                try {
                    out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile, true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                isStop = false;
                stop.setClickable(true);
                start.setClickable(false);
                Download();
                DownloadThread.start();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download Start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        final int sampleRate = 44100;
        final int minBufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

        mAudioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                minBufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        mDecoder = new Decoder();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStream in = new URL(url)
                            .openConnection()
                            .getInputStream();
                    final Bitstream bitstream = new Bitstream(in);

                    final int READ_THRESHOLD = 2147483647;
                    int framesReaded = READ_THRESHOLD;

                    Header header;
                    for (; framesReaded-- > 0 && (header = bitstream.readFrame()) != null; ) {
                        SampleBuffer sampleBuffer = (SampleBuffer) mDecoder.decodeFrame(header, bitstream);
                        short[] buffer = sampleBuffer.getBuffer();
                        mAudioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                        bitstream.closeFrame();

                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        thread.start();

        mAudioTrack.play();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mAudioTrack.stop();
    }

    void Download() {
        DownloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    InputStream in = new URL(url)
                            .openConnection()
                            .getInputStream();
                    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
                    do {
                        int numread = 0;
                        numread = in.read(buf);
                        if (numread > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
                        }
                    } while (!isStop);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for help it would be more helpful if you can explain these classes : Bitstream ,Decoder,SampleBuffer  how to resolve it.

Comment: download https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3QOuxsFDJ3sWnJVR1BxM1pKZ3M jar file and place it into your libs folder and in android gradle compile with compile files('libs/jl1.0.1.jar').also import this import javazoom.jl.decoder.Bitstream;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Decoder;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.Header;
import javazoom.jl.decoder.SampleBuffer;

Comment: Thanks for help @asim again but i have run the code but there is no option to forward and rewind the stream can you please help me regarding this i will be very thankful to you i need the exact functionality like the V Radio Recorder.